# Can we sort an Excel worksheet based on one column?

Tags: vba, sorting, excel

I have an Excel worksheet and would like for all its values to be sorted in an alphabetical order.  By instance, let's say I have:

```
Col 1 | Col 2
------+-------
   z  |   26
------+-------
   a  |   1
------+-------
```

I would like to have

```
Col 1 | Col 2
------+-------
   a  |   1
------+-------
   z  |   26
------+-------
```

and not

```
Col 1 | Col 2
------+-------
   a  |   26
------+-------
   z  |   1
------+-------
```

I know I can sort the first column using

```
Target.EntireColumn.Sort Key1:=Target, Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlGuess,
OrderCustom:=1, MatchCase:=False, Orientation:=xlTopToBottom
```

But sorting the first column like this produces the result I don't want.

Anyone has any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    Columns("D:D").Select
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Sort.SortFields.Clear
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("D1"), _
    SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Sort
    .SetRange Range("A1:D6")
    .Header = xlNo
    .MatchCase = False
    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
    .SortMethod = xlPinYin
    .Apply
End With
```

Comment: this is REALLY close, I forgot to mention two things:  the table doesn't always have the same number of rows and I would like for the first row to be ignored since its a header.  Do you think that could be done?

Comment: Alright I figuredt out how to keep the first row unaffacted.  All I need is the range.  I was also wondering if it would be possible to sort by two columns...

Comment: Change First Line to select the starting column for instance `Columns("B:B").Select` and change `Key:=Range("B2")` and change `Range("B2:C2555")`